How can I read each file in a directory and directly run a function in node readdir?
my understanding of fs.readdir in node is that it reads all files in a directory asynchronously, but only makes them available as an array once they're all fulfilled. Is it possible to run a function on each file as soon as that individual file is ready (i.e. not to wait for all of them)?
My current implementation is as follows:
fs.readdir(DIR, async (err, files) => {
      if(err) console.log(err)
      const promises = files.map(file => doSomething(file))
      try {
        await Promise.allSettled(promises);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error processing array:', error);
      }  
})

which runs doSomething on each file asynchronously but that still waits for all files to be determined first

How about fs.readdirSync()?

It sounds like you're really looking for a node.js version of inotifywait(), which will let you know when a new file has been written rather than looping over the directory.

As of node 12, you can use the fs.Dir class.
An example of this:
import { opendir } from 'node:fs/promises';

try {
  const dir = await opendir('./');
  for await (const dirent of dir) {
    doSomething(dirent.name);
  }

} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}

You'll still need to wait for the opendir call to finish at the start, but it should only read each entry in the directory as it iterates through them in the for loop.
You can find the documentation here: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#class-fsdir
PS: I'd be really interested to hear what your use case is where this level of optimisation is needed.  Have you just got an absolutely huge directory containing loads of individual files?

I'm also interested to hear the use case. In the case that there's an enormous quantity of entries (will take more time to iterate) and those entries are likely to be modified during iteration, it's especially important to note a caveat in the documentation: "Directory entries returned by this iterator are in no particular order as provided by the operating system's underlying directory mechanisms. Entries added or removed while iterating over the directory might not be included in the iteration results."
